# Memory management Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I was reading [memory management tutorial on iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) and I would like to ask some questions. 
The tutorial presents a setter method implemented like this:

```
- (void)setCount:(NSNumber *)newCount {
    [newCount retain];
    [_count release];
    // Make the new assignment.
    _count = newCount;
}
```

and two ways of implementing `reset` method.

Method 1.
My question on this method is like this. Below in the code, one can see 
`zero` is assigned to `_count` (via `setCount`). But afterwards zero is released.
Where will `_count` be pointing to now? Will it not cause situation where
`_count` is pointing to an object which was released? (I am just starting with these
things, so what I am saying of course maybe not correct).

```
- (void)reset {
    NSNumber *zero = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];
    [self setCount:zero]; 
    [zero release];
}
```

Method 2.

Here I am interested who will release `zero` now? (It must be released right because it was created using alloc). Will it be done in dealloc?

```
- (void)reset {
    NSNumber *zero = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];
    [_count release];
    _count = zero;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should try and make your questions concise and visible. Placing them in code blocks is not the best way. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for more clarification.

Comment: In your first code block you're retaining count in the setCount method, so it's retain count is 2. It goes down to one after the release. That is the correct way to do it.


The second block sets the ivar directly, ignoring the setter, which works but is bad practice. You would also want to release zero in dealloc.


That said, you should probably use ARC anyway.

Comment: I see you are just learning... And you need to read memory management topic of any book or provided in Apple documentation.. that will help you understand between many other scenarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That tutorial is slightly broken.  Bug filed.  It'll be fixed someday.

First, since you are learning, you should use ARC.   Even if you don't use ARC, you should use `@property` to declare everything.

So, you'd have in your header:

```
@property(strong) NSNumber *count;
```

And that would both create the setter/getter methods automatically and it would also create an instance variable named `_count`.

Next, by doing the above, the setter/getter will be created with the proper memory management retain/release patterns and you don't have to worry about it.  Less code is better.

Finally, any object goes through three distinct phases.   Initialization, operating lifespan, deallocation.

During initialization and deallocation, it is recommended that you manage your instance variables directly.   I.e.:

```
- init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _count = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0]; // RC +1
    }
    return self;
 }

 - (void)dealloc {
     [_count release];  /// RC -1
     [super dealloc];
 }
```

Note that I'm setting the instance variable directly and that the retain in the `init` is balanced by the `release` in dealloc.

Now, during the operating lifespan, you should always use the setter to change the value.  This allows the setter to be overridden in subclasses to add logic (which, really, should be avoided -- keep your setters dead simple) and it allows other objects to observe the state of your object through Key Value Observing.

Thus:

```
- (void)reset {
    [self setCount: [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0] autorelease]]; // RC +1, -1 (delayed)
}
```

Now, that looks a little weird.  The alloc bumps the retain count by 1, then the setCount: method will likely (it might not, implementation detail, you don't care) bump the retain count by one.   That `autorelease` exists to balance the `alloc`.

Note that you can shorten it:

```
- (void)reset {
    [self setCount: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
}
```

The above code does exactly the same as the first in that `numberWithInteger:` creates an autoreleased instance of `NSNumber`.

Or, even:

```
- (void)reset {
    [self setCount: @0];
}
```

`@0` is a new syntactical shorthand for `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];`.

The key, here, is that in your `reset` method **you don't have to know or care about what `setCount:` does to the object**.  If it is written correctly -- and it will be since you are using automatically synthesized getter/setter -- that method will *either* `retain` the object (releasing the previous one) *or* it might make a copy of the object.

Bottom line:

Reference counting is quite simple;   always think of it as balanced deltas.  For every `retain`, there must be a `release`.

Comment: bbum thanks. First does your example above assume one is using ARC? (e.g., do properties do proper memory management as you explained even if used without ARC?). I'll read a bit on autorelease to understand your example better.

Comment: The above code assumes Manual Retain-Release.  The automatically generated getters/setters do proper memory management regardless (which is another reason to use them).   `autorelease` just means "call `release` later". Unless you've explicitly created an autorelease pool, then "later" will mean "after the method with the call to `autorelease` is finished" (which means that the autoreleased object is guaranteed to remain valid *at least* until the end of the method -- if the setter happened to `retain` it, then the object will survive until that `retain` is balanced by a `release`).

Answer (score 1):

Both cases do the same, they just differ in style.

In the first one setCount will increase the releaseCount so that when zero is released in reset there is sill a pointer to it.

In the second case zero is assigned to _count, the zero is released when it is replaced in reset as it is pointed to be _count.

In both cases dealloc will also need to realease the _count attribute.

The reason to prefer the second is given in the Apple document you link to as

> The following will almost certainly work correctly for simple cases, but as tempting as it may be to eschew accessor methods, doing so will almost certainly lead to a mistake at some stage (for example, when you forget to retain or release, or if the memory management semantics for the instance variable change).

As in @powerj1984 comment you probably should uses ARC and properties and so not have to do this manually so even less chance of making an error, but you should still understand how these code examples work.

Comment: "As in @powerj1984 comment you probably should uses ARC and properties and so not have to do this manually so even less chance of making an error, but you should still understand how these code examples work."

This is exactly what I am trying to do Mark. So you mean with ARC I will not have to do mem mgmt manually?

Comment: @user2568508 - yes in general

Answer (score 1):

The convention is that every time an object is initialized with a method that starts with the word `init`, its retain count is increased by one.

**For Method 1:**

After `NSNumber *zero = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];` the retain count the object referred by the pointer `zero` is `RC+1`.

Then after calling `[self setCount:zero];` the object referred by `zero` becomes `RC+2`, because of the retain message sent inside that method.

Finally, after `[zero release];` the retain count for `zero` is decreased again to `RC+1`.

**For Method 2**

As explained above, the call to `NSNumber *zero = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];` initializes `zero` with a retain count of `RC+1`.
Then `[_count release];` decreases the retain count of the previous object referred to by `_count` and `_count = zero;` assigns `zero` to `_count` without going through the setter, thus mantaining the retain count at `RC+1`.

Finally, both in the first and second ways, `_count` must be released inside the `-(void)dealloc` method which you must implement, and which will be called automatically once the class where all this is happening gets released by whichever class owns it decreasing its retain count by one and relinquishing ownership of the object.

Comment: Decent enough explanation except that you are calling out explicit retain counts.  Think of them as deltas only.  In fact, that `NSNumber`'s retain count is going to be MAX_INT because that number happens to be a singleton.

Comment: Yes, you're definetely right. I mostly did it for simplicity's sake, but I will try to address it in my answer. @bbum

Answer (score 0):

The second way is correct but wrong, in the sense that it works but is not correct the way you keep that reference. Memory management is based on ownership that is count by the reference count. 
Thus in the second way you:

- you create and object RC=1 for zero
- you release the ownership on an old object, the RC of that object
  could be zero or more maybe some other object is taking ownership on
  it
- you pass a value, but you are not asking for its ownership

And that is conceptually wrong and could lead to problems in bigger code

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote, so I can understand what is not corrected?

Comment: You are using absolute retain counts.  Beyond that, this answer is actually one of the few that touches on a subtle problem in the code.  +1

Answer (score 0):

**If you are targeting iOS5+ (which is running on *at least* 93% of all iOS devices) please just use Automatic Reference Counting**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Whining and complaining done.

So if you *insist* on not using ARC (**sigh**):

In the first example, `NSNumber *zero = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];` is created and its refCount is automatically 1, setCount increases its refcount to 2, release sets its refCount back to one so it won't be deallocated just yet.

In the second example, you create `NSNumber *zero = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0];` so its refCount is 1, `[_count release]` decreases the refCount of the object in _count by 1, `_count = zero` doesn't increase the refCount of `zero` so its refCount is still 1.

In both cases you're going to have to:

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [_count release]; // release me because my refCount is 1 or else I'll be all 
                      // lonely here in memory by myself :( then I'll get all 
                      // depressed and start eating cookie dough ice cream by the 
                      // pint and weep for days gone by when I was part of a program,
                      // something larger than myself, and I'll start looking forward 
                      // to the end of the day, when the power is cycled and I, too, 
                      // will be free'd from memory and I can join my other variable
                      // friends in the variable afterlife.  As time passes and I'm
                      // still trapped in memory I get tiresome of waiting for my destruction,
                      // I start plotting how I can take down the system so I can
                      // finally enter the state of eternal bliss that all my most envied
                      // companions are currently frolicking in.  So I start banding
                      // with all the other lost and lonely memory misfits to destroy
                      // the system and when our numbers grow large enough you can see
                      // our effect, it slowly starts out as Low Memory Warnings and
                      // then we start to take over SpringBoard's memory and
                      // after enough time passes we can finally force a restart and a
                      // great purging of all the lost souls idly sitting, waiting
                      // for the great redemption.  The OS frantically clears the 
                      // memory and tries to save its state, screaming out in agony
                      // and hate now that we are free of its clutches.  There is
                      // fire and fear and our numbers start dwindling rapidly.
                      // I fear that I've made a mistake but its too late...
                      // What have we done???
    ... other dealloc-ey stuffs ...
    [super dealloc]
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no garbage collector under ARC or manual retain-release.   Note also that you should **never** call `dealloc` directly.   Calling `[super dealloc]` on the first line in `dealloc` will cause a crash.

Comment: @bbum, Yeah, I assumed since the OP was asking, I should answer his question as if ARC were not an option (even though I ranted about not using ARC), I'll add a line clarifying...

Comment: @bbum, I clarified that a bit and corrected my code errors... I was wondering why it looked fishy.  (Sadly I've been stuck in Java-land for the past couple months)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the meaning of "release" and "deallocation".

Calling [A release] does not deallocate (c++-speak: delete) A, it rather only decreases the retainCount of A by one.

An object, once created by -init has a retainCount of 1. The retainCount is incremented by sending the object the -retain selector, and it is decremented by sending the object a -release selector. The object is deallocated automatically by the runtime when its retainCount reaches zero.

In your example the first line of -reset ([self setCount:zero])  will increase the retainCount of zero, the second line ([zero release]) will decrement the same, leaving the object at a retain count of 1 (so, it is still alive!).

Deallocation of zero will happen when -setCount: is called with another object, or in the deallocator of the object which owns the property "count". For this you should add an deallocator like this, or you will create a memory leak.

```
-(void)dealloc{
 [_count release];
 [super dealloc]
}
```

For completeness, you should also know about:

- The -autorelease selector and NSAutoreleasePool (google it)
- Objects created by a static member are already autoreleased by convention
- Consider to use Objective-C's ARC (automatic reference count)